# Zariski density of conjugates of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in $Sp_{2g}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, symplectic-group

Let $Sp_2g$ be the symplectic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as a subgroup of $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$ (the embedding that I have in mind is $A\to \begin{pmatrix} 
A& 0\\
0& I_{2g-2}
\end{pmatrix}$, but you can take any algebraic group embedding which yields a positive answer to the following question).
Is it true that there eixst finitely many $g_i\in Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that the $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski closure of $\cup_i g_i SL_2(\mathbb{Z})g_i^{-1}$ is equal to $Sp_{2g}$? i.e. that this union is Zariski-dense in $Sp_{2g}$? If yes, what conditions and restrictions should these elements satisfy? How should the $g_i$ be chosen? I would appreciate any result, comments or reference in this direction.

Comment: In order for this question to be well-defined, you might need to say how $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is considered as a subgroup of $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @ Jeremy Rouse, I added explanation to the question. But any embedding which gives a positive answer is welcome!

Answer (score 6):

This seems impossible to me, at least with the kind of embedding considered or anything remotely close to it. I'll think classically, in terms of $\mathbb{C}$ points. Your embedding $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ sits inside $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) \subset Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$. Note that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is three dimensional. So the Zariski closure of $\bigcup g_i SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) g_i^{-1}$ is contained in the closed subscheme $\bigcup g_i SL_2(\mathbb{C}) g_i^{-1}$. But the latter is a union of finitely many $3$-dimensional varieties, so it can't fill up the $2g^2+g>3$ dimensional variety $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$.

This argument applies whenever the map $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$ extends to a map $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) \to Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$. If you just ask for a map of abstract groups, ignoring algebraic geometry, I don't know what to expect.

Comment: There are embeddings $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$ with Zariski dense images since the domain group is a free product modulo its center.

Comment: @Misha You should post the details!

Comment: Indeed, the desired $\mathbb{Q}$ closure is $Sp_{2g}$ if and only if the image of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is itself Zariski dense (since $Sp_{2g}$ is an irreducible variety).

Comment: I guess the point is really those embeddings coming from algebraic group homomorphisms. Otherwise this is another topic and I would certainly not call "$SL_2(Z)"$ the image of any homomorphism from $SL_2(Z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. As Ycor mentioned, the embeddings should be algebraic. I will add this to the question. @Misha: I Would like to know the details of those examples!

Comment: If the embedding is algebraic, then the answer to the question is never, unless $g=1$.

Comment: If the embedding is $\mathbb{Q}$ algebraic, then the answer to the question is never, unless $g=1$. This is the answer of David. There is the possibility that the $\mathbb{Q}$ closure is different from the $\mathbb{C}$-closure; in that case, what you are asking is that under an algebraic (but not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$-) representation, the image of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ should be $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski dense in $Sp_{2g}$; there do exist such embeddings; take a standard embedding over $\mathbb{Q}$ and conjugate it by a "transcendental" element.

Comment: @Venkataraman, thank you very much for the nice answer. Could you explain why the image of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is dense in $Sp_{2g}$ after conjugating with transcendental elements?

Comment: @Venkataraman On reflection, I don't see this either. Certainly, the image of one element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ isn't $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski dense after conjugation by a transcendental (for example, its trace will still be an integer), so it isn't obvious to me that the Zariski conjugate of the whole$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ becomes $\mathbb{Q}$-Zariski dense.

Comment: the latter is not really a question about $SL_2(Z)$, since it boils down to understanding whether the conjugate of the standard copy $H$ of $SL_2(Q)$ (as given in the question) by a transcendental element (in some sense) is $Q$-Zariski dense. Anyway, since the set of $Q$-algebraic subgroups is countable and since the set of $g$ conjugating $H$ into a given algebraic proper subgroup is a proper subvariety, whenever we take $g$ outside this countable union we have $gHg^{-1}$ $Q$-Zariski dense.

Comment: @ Darius: YCor's comment  answers your question.

Comment: @David: The $\mathbb{Q}$ closure is the smallest $\mathbb{Q}$-defined  subvariety containing the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Now, YCor's comment implies that the set of $g$ conjugating this copy of $SL_2(Z)$ into a proper $Q$ variety $W$ is a proper $Q$-subvariety $W'$. If $g$ is "sufficiently transcendental" (i.e. lies outside these countably many $W'$), then the $Q$ closure of the conjugate of $SL(2,Z)$ by $g$ is all of $Sp_{2g}$.

Comment: Rather than working with the image of $SL_2$, one can look at its image in the space of characteristic polynomials. This is necessarily $1$-dimensional and conjugacy-invariant, so taking the union of conjugates does not affect this. Because it is one-dimensional in a $g$-dimensional space, it is not dense. This works even if the embedding is only defined over $\mathbb C$, because any $2g$-dimensional algebraic representation of $SL_2$ is conjugate over $\mathbb C$ to one defined over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @YCor I could be wrong, but I don't see why the Zariski closure must be an algebraic subgroup. I think in situations like the Mumford-Tate group, we define the closure to be the minimal Zariski closed subgroup containing the torus by fiat.

Comment: @WillSawin I'm talking of the Zariski closure of the image of the representation of $SL_2(Z)$ (not of the union of conjugates), and Zariski closure of a subgroup is clearly a subgroup. Then the question is about the reunion of conjugates of this algebraic subgroup.

Comment: @YCor The problem is that the $\mathbb Q$-closure of the product $G \times G$ may be smaller than the product of the $\mathbb Q$-closure, so it is not necessarily a subgroup.

Comment: @YCor Consider the subgroup $\begin{pmatrix} (1+\lambda)/2 & \pi^{-1}(1-\lambda)/2 \\\pi (1-\lambda)/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda$ a parameter and $\pi$ a transcendental. The $\mathbb Q$-Zariski closure is clearly $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & a \end{pmatrix}$ with $bc = (1-a)^2$, which is not a subgroup. The $\mathbb Q$-closure of the product of two copies is clearly at most $3$-dimensional, as it has $3$ parameters $\pi,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, so it cannot be the product of two two-dimensional varieties.

Comment: @WillSawin You're right (typo: in the 22 position you mean $(1+\lambda)/2$). Even a subgroup of order 2 can have a non-subgroup as $\mathbf{Q}$-Zariski closure: the group of order 2 generated by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \pi\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ has $\mathbf{Q}$-Zariski closure the union of the singleton identity and all matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1 & x\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$. So indeed my argument was not correct; thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @YCor An interesting corollary is that, though it is commonly said in casual conversation that the Mumford-Tate group is the $\mathbb Q$-Zariski closure of the Hodge torus, this is not actually correct.

Comment: @ somebody please put me out of my misery: in @YCor's argument, why do you need that the $\mathbb{Q}$-closure is a subgroup? There are only countably many $\mathbb{Q}$-subvarieties of $Sp_{2g}$ and if the conjugation avoids all of them, (which can be ensured by measure theory?), then the conjugate subgroup has the property that the $Q$-closure is all of $Sp_{2g}$.

Comment: Oops! I think there was a mistake in my "argument"; the measure theory argument does not seem to work

Comment: @Venkataramana: indeed there something additional to check: that for every proper $Q$-subvariety $X$ (and not only proper $Q$-subgroup), the set of $g$ conjugating $H$ (the standard copy of $SL_2$) into $X$ is a proper subvariety. But this seems to be false, if we define $X$ to be the set of matrices having 1 as eigenvalue with multiplicity $\ge 2g-2$.

Answer (score 5):

Even for any algebraic group embedding of $SL_2$ into $Sp_{2g}$, with an arbitrary amount of conjugation by arbitrary elements, the answer is no. Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$ in $SL_2$. Its image under the algebraic group embedding is some $2g \times 2g$ matrix whose eigenvalues are powers of $\lambda$. The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is some $2g$-tuple of polynomials in $\lambda$, all defined over $\mathbb Z$, whose image is a $1$-dimensional subvariety, defined over $\mathbb Q$, of the space of polynomials.

Because elements conjugate to this one are dense in $SL_2(\mathbb C)$, the image of every element of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ under the characteristic polynomial map is contained in this $1$-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-subvariety. The same is true for any number (even an infinite number) of conjugate copies of $SL_2$.  Because the characteristic polynomials of elements of $Sp_{2g}$ form a $g$-dimensional variety, there is no way this union can be $\mathbb Q$-Zariski dense.

Answer (score 3):

As requested, here is a construction (a sketch only) of faithful representations $PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ to $PSp(n, {\mathbb Z})$ with Zariski dense images. I will add some details when and if I have time.

I will work modulo the center(s), taking care of the latter takes extra effort. First note that $\Gamma=PSp(n, {\mathbb Z})$ contains involutions $\sigma$ which act as Cartan involutions on the associated symmetric space of $Sp(n, {\mathbb R})$. Let $\tau$ denote an order 3 element of $PSp(n, {\mathbb Z})$ coming  from the block-diagonal embedding of $SL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ as in your question. Now, choose a *generic sufficiently long* (say, in the word metric, but you can also use a matrix norm) element $\gamma\in \Gamma$ and consider the representation $PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})\cong Z_3 \star Z_2\to \Gamma$ sending the generator of $Z_3$ to $\tau$ and the generator of $Z_2$ to the conjugate $\gamma \sigma \gamma^{-1}$. The claim is that such representations do the job.  A proof is (mostly) a certain ping-pong argument.

Of course, I recognize that this is not what OP had in mind, but it is a response to a remark in David's answer.

Comment: what do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\star \mathbb{Z}_{3}$? Sorry, since I am not an Experte in the field!

Comment: $\star$ (more usually $\ast$) denotes the free product of groups, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product. Here $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a (somewhat controversial) notation for the cyclic group on $n$ elements (common for some group theoretists, but in conflict with $n$-adic numbers).

Comment: @YCor, thank you very much, yes of course I know what $Z_2$ means, I meant only the star notation.

Answer (score 2):

A complement to David's answer. Zariski dense (faithful) representations of the $2, 4, 5$ triangle group are constructed by Long and Thistlethwaite's [*Zariski dense surface subgroups in $SL(4, \mathbb{Z}).$*](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~long/pubpdf/sl4z_bw.pdf) This is not exactly easy (the paper is nicely written, though).